# iOS Auto Layout Dynamic Button Placement

Tags: ios, uitableview, constraints, autolayout

I have a prototype cell with two stacked labels followed by a view that contains up to three buttons. It is possible for 0, 1, 2 or 3 buttons to be visible for any given cell (based on web xml file). I would like the layout to be as follows (X represents buttons)

3 Buttons

```
  |       |                   
  | X X X |         
  |       |
```

2 Buttons

```
  |       |                   
  | X   X |         
  |       |
```

1 Button

```
  |       |                   
  |   X   |         
  |       |
```

My table cell code sets the frame of each button depending on the total number of buttons in the cell. However the frame does seem to work until the cell is loaded for the second time (i.e scroll so the cell is out of range and then back to it). Last time this occurred it was due to layout constraints. Question is, how do i set up the constraints in storyboard to allow for each button to be in on of many locations? Currently each button is pinned to top, bottom and leading edge of the button view. I know the leading edge constraint is causing the issue, but not sure what to use instead as the storyboard forces it. Or is there something I can do in my cellForRowAtIndexPath method?  Here is relevant code from that method

```
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"localdiningTableCell";

        mhgiLocalDiningCell *diningcell = (mhgiLocalDiningCell*)[tableView
                                           dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (diningcell == nil) {
            diningcell = [[mhgiLocalDiningCell alloc]
                          initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                          reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

        mhgiDiningXmlObject *object = [self.xmlParser.allItems objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

        CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(280.0f, MAXFLOAT);

        CGSize labelSize = [[object Name] sizeWithFont:diningcell.nameLabel.font constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake (10, 10, 280.0f, labelSize.height);
        diningcell.nameLabel.frame = frame;
        diningcell.nameLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        diningcell.nameLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        diningcell.nameLabel.text= [object Name];
        CGFloat nextYVal = diningcell.nameLabel.frame.origin.y + diningcell.nameLabel.frame.size.height + 10.0f;



        NSString *descrText = @"";
        if (![[object Type] isEqualToString:@""]){
            descrText = [descrText stringByAppendingString:[object Type]];
            descrText = [descrText stringByAppendingString:@"\n"];
        }
        descrText = [descrText stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@, %@", [object Street], [object City], [object State]]];
        descrText = [descrText stringByAppendingString:@"\n"];
        descrText = [descrText stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ miles from the hotel", [object Distance]]];




        labelSize = [descrText sizeWithFont:diningcell.typeLabel.font constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        frame = CGRectMake (10, nextYVal, 280.0f, labelSize.height);
        diningcell.typeLabel.frame = frame;
        diningcell.typeLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        diningcell.typeLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        diningcell.typeLabel.text = descrText;
        nextYVal += diningcell.typeLabel.frame.origin.y + diningcell.typeLabel.frame.size.height + 10.0f;


        diningcell.ussite= [object UrbanSpoon];
        diningcell.website= [object Website];
        diningcell.dirsite= [object Maps];

        NSMutableArray* buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [buttons removeAllObjects];


        if ([[object Website] isEqualToString:@""]){
            [diningcell.websiteButton setHidden:TRUE];
        }
        else
        {
            [diningcell.websiteButton setHidden:FALSE];
            [buttons addObject:diningcell.websiteButton];
        }



        if ([[object UrbanSpoon] isEqualToString:@""]){
            [diningcell.usButton setHidden:TRUE];
        }
        else
        {
            [diningcell.usButton setHidden:FALSE];
            [buttons addObject:diningcell.usButton];
        }

        if ([[object Maps] isEqualToString:@""]){
            [diningcell.dirButton setHidden:TRUE];
        }
        else
        {
            [diningcell.dirButton setHidden:FALSE];
            [buttons addObject:diningcell.dirButton];
        }




        if (buttons.count == 1){
            [[buttons objectAtIndex:0] setCenter:CGPointMake(150.0f, 25.0f)];

        }
        else if (buttons.count == 2){
            [[buttons objectAtIndex:0] setCenter:CGPointMake(75.0f, 25.0f)];

            [[buttons objectAtIndex:1] setCenter:CGPointMake(225.0f, 25.0f)];
        }
        else if (buttons.count == 3){
            [[buttons objectAtIndex:0] setCenter:CGPointMake(75.0f, 25.0f)];

            [[buttons objectAtIndex:1] setCenter:CGPointMake(150.0f, 25.0f)];

            [[buttons objectAtIndex:2] setCenter:CGPointMake(225.0f, 25.0f)];
        }

        return diningcell;
```

**UPDATE**
I created a custom view to try and over come the layout issues. The view just houses four buttons and places them on the layoutviews method. I added a view of the custom class to my prototype cell and the layout seems to work. However when I change directions in the scrollveiw (i.e down then up, up then down) some of the cells get misaligned. See image below.

[Image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uaegcrc0fseloyw/iOS%20Simulator%20Screen%20shot%20Aug%2022,%202013%2010.13.31%20PM.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use different prototypes for the three cell types and set the alignment up in the storyboard.  You'd end up with very little code required.  Just dequeue a cell of the appropriate type in cellForRowAtIndexPath: and set it up - no need to manipulate the frames directly.

Comment: I thought about using this approach, however I wanted a generic view that would allow for up to 3 buttons from a set of five choices (call, download, website, urbanspoon and directions). I dont remember combination math, but the five choose three plus five choose 2 plus... would lead to a lot of prototype cells.

Comment: Using this approach, you could have three prototypes, with one, two and three buttons respectively.  Change the button labels at runtime, but don't change the placement.

Comment: I guess and change the icon, however I would have to duplicate the prototype cells in all the tables I wish to use the custom view. I got the custom cell to work by setting the width of each label in the XIB. Prior to that I was setting the width programatically to cell width/ number of labels. This didnt seem to work as the label frame size would not report the correct height for the given width.

Comment: For example, say the cell width is 300 and there are three buttons. To allow for padding I would say each label is given a width of 80. I would set the label frame width to 80 and then call the sizetofit method. If the label is too long for a width of 80 (multiple lines), the frame size height returned after the sizetofit call was not adjusted. It simply returned the height given in the XIB (one line).